# Howto display popup/tooltip below single word in html input field

Tags: javascript

I want todo some spellchecking on an html input field. For this i would like to highlight the wrong word and display alternatives down under the word.

Functionality in background is already working, ight now i am using http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/ (mentioned by siddhartha).
I understand and found examples how this can be done on a rich text field but not on a single line input `<input type="text" value="Here iz somme...">`.
My problem is that i do not get the word select box on the right place. If html input is "Here iz somme" and i click 'Iz', I can't put the popup below that text.

This is how it should look like (Imagine "Here iz somme badlyy speldt worddz" is html input value)

[image]

Comment: you mean '<input type'text'..'

Comment: yes and extended question.

Comment: how are you doing it originally? if you can somehow manipulate a text, you can just access the value of the input element and go on from there i suppose

Comment: have you tried `onmouseover`?

Comment: What do you mean by "do not get the word select box on the right place"? Your screenshot is ok, as for me. Please show us 'bad' screenshot :)

Comment: Please update your title to "javascript misspelled: show correct words" or something like that. Title is really confusing and doesn't relate to your problem.

Comment: I think the title exactly explains my problem. Ok, just replace s/create/display

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jquery plugin.. Please check it here

http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/

Workaround can be make your text area look like input text, I mean style it look like Input field

HTML:

```
<textarea id="textarea-content" rows="1" style="width:90%" spellcheck="false">Here iz somme badlyy speldt worddz</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
textarea
{
   resize: none;
   border:solid 1px #d2d2d2;
   background: #fff;
   color: #333;
   height: 44px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am using exactly that jquery plugin, but i am unable to show box under wrong words on input fields. (like shown in screenshot above). Extended my question

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look to [BJSpell](http://code.google.com/p/bjspell/) - it is a good implementation in javascript plus Hunspell dictionaries can be used.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Functionality in background is already working. my only problem is that i do not get the word select box on the right place. i havbe extended my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to do that without javascript. So my suggestion is to use javascript.

If we have "Here iz somme badlyy speldt worddz". When we click certain bad word then we capture mouse position with javascript(we can use jquery) then show the popup base on the position that we get from mouse position.